# Let $(V, \Vert.\Vert)$ be a normed vectorspace. Then $V$ is separable iff $V$ has a total countable subset

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, separable-spaces

**Prove that:**

> Let $(V, \Vert.\Vert)$ be a normed vectorspace. Then $V$ is separable
>    iff $V$ has a total countable subset

**Relevant definitions:**

> A total subset in a normed vector space $V$ is a subset $T \subseteq
>  V$ such that $\overline{span T} = V$
>
> $V$ is called separable iff it has a countable dense subset

**My attempt**:

$\boxed{\Rightarrow}$ Let $A$ be a countable dense subset in $V$. Then we have $\overline{A}= V$ and hence $span \overline{A} = V$. Now, because addition and scalar multiplication in vector spaces are continuous functions, and for a continuous function $f$ we have $f(\overline{A}) \subseteq \overline{f(A)}$, it follows that $\overline{span A} = V$ and hence $A$ is a countable total subset of $V$

$\boxed{\Leftarrow}$ Let $A$ be a total countable total subspace in $V$. Then $\overline{span A} = V$.

I'm stuck here. It is clear that we won't be able to prove that $span(A)$ is countable, because easy counterexamples can be found. So my idea was to show that $A$ is dense in $V$, given the denseness of $span(A)$ in $V$, but I was unsuccesful in doing this.

Is what I did correct? How can I complete the proof?

Comment: Hint: If $A$ is countable then the set of linear combinations of vectors in $A$ using only rational coefficients is countable.

Comment: Doesn't this hint assume that V is a real vector space?

Comment: I suppose it does. Surely you can come up with a modified version that works in the complex case....

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Your hint helped me solve this a while ago. Post it as an answer and I'll upvote and accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Recall how the separabiity of $C[0,1]$ follows from the Weierstrass approximation theorem.

Comment: What does a set of continuous functions have to do with an abstract normed space?

Comment: The idea was that if you remember how this special case is proved, you'll have the key for the more general result. Perhaps I didn't say it well. I'll edit.